# JavaScript Doing addition and subtraction on specific parts of an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers and I want to subtract 9 from any number larger than 9. I have the code below and it is not giving an error, but it is not doing anything. Tried the .map method and several other ways such as for loops. This has been my first js project so I am not proficient in much. Been stuck on this for a while so I would love to get some help.

evenSum = [4,  4, 0, 12, 0, 10, 2,  8]

evenSum.forEach(evenSums =>{
if(evenSums > 9){
return evenSums - 9
}
})

Comment: You've mis-interpreted what `.forEach()` does. You don't do anything my returning the value. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

```js
evenSum = [4, 4, 0, 12, 0, 10, 2, 8]

let res = evenSum.map(evenSums => evenSums > 9 ? evenSums - 9 : evenSums)

console.log(res)
```